# when editing product from backend and saving an error showing 'Tier prices data should be array, but actually other type is received'

Tags: magento2, price, tierprice

I am trying to edit a product from the backend and clicked save button. Then an error showing that '*Tier prices data should be array, but actually other type is received*' and edited information is reverting. Can you please help me in this?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

To check tier_price attribute_id from the "eav_attribute" table, search

SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code="tier_price"
which is 91.

And then search entry for 91 attribute_id value from catalog_product_entity_decimal

SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE attribute_id=91

And then delete the entry from the table.

It works for me.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. In my case tier_price has the attribute_id 92 though.